# Evaluation of nested Integral

Tags: calculus

I'm ultimately interested in:
$$S =  \int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\int_0^{x_{n-1}}\dots\int_0^{x_2}\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\ \bigg]\ dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$$

But I realized it may be simplest to just consider one term as the summation and the integrals can be interchanged in this case. My thought process is the following:

$$I = \int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\int_0^{x_{n-1}}\dots\int_0^{x_2}\bigg[\ x_k^2\ \bigg]\ dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\dots\int_0^{x_{k+1}}x_k^2\left[\int_0^{x_k}\int_0^{x_2}\ 1\ dx_1\dots dx_{k-1}\right]\ dx_k\dots dx_n$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\dots\int_0^{x_{k+1}}\left[\frac{x_k^{k+1}}{(k-1)!}\right]\ dx_k\dots dx_n$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{kx_n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\ dx_n= k\left[(n+2)!\right]^{-1}$$
Such that the original summation becomes:
$$S = \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n+2)!}$$
Is this line of reasoning accurate? I plan to work out something similar for
$$\int_0^1\dots\int_0^{x_2}\left[x_k\cdot x_{k-1}\right]dx_1\dots dx_n,\ k\in\{2,...,n\}$$

Comment: Is there any significance to the $n$ in the upper limit of the sum being the same $n$ that indexes the outermost variable of integration?

Comment: In the context of my problem they are the same $n$

Comment: For $n=1$ the integral is $1/3$, whereas your result gives $S=1/6$. The mistake is in the last line where the integrand should be $k(k+1)x_n^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ and hence $S=1/(3 (n-1)!)$. Apart from that the approach is just fine.